# Static Initializing pattern

Tags: c#, initialization

What is the best way to initialize static fields via a static *init* method and afterwards make sure that the method is never called again? (no more than once during the lifetime of the program)

This is an example of what I currently thought of, it seems pretty simple to me but I couldn't find any examples of similar patterns that deal with this:

```
class Entity
{
    static Manager manager;
    static bool isInitialized;

    public static void Initialize(Manager manager)
    {
        if (isInitialized)
            throw Exception("Class Entity already initialized."
                 + "Do not call Entity.Initialize() twice.");
        isInitialized = true;
        Entity.manager = manager;

    }
}
```

Comment: Is 'Manager' a singleton? I think you're better off looking into IoC containers for this.

Comment: You may find the `Lazy<T>` class of interest.

Comment: Just want to draw your attention to the fact that Singletons can introduce dependencies and brittleness in you applications - [here is a good blog](http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/flaw-brittle-global-state-singletons/) to help explain and avoid. As @n8wrl stated, look at using dependency injection.

Comment: What you *could* do is [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.editorbrowsableattribute.aspx). You can hide the method from IntelliSense and similar with this attribute. Stops it from cluttering up the dropdown too.

Comment: `Manager` does not implement the Singleton pattern. There is however only one instance of `Manager` and it is created at program launch.

Answer (score 6):

> What is the best way to initialize static fields via a static init method and afterwards make sure that the method is never called again?

Do you really *have* to do this? Why do you not want to create an instance of `Manager` and make it available to code which relies on it through dependency injection? That would make your code much cleaner:

- You'd allow it to be testable with different initialization paths
- You wouldn't need any checking for "bad" duplicate initialization
- You wouldn't need to structure your calling code to specify a single initialization point for this class. (You may need to do something similar for the IoC container of course...)
- You'd allow your code which depends on it to be more testable too
- The code which depends on `Manager` would be express that dependency in a clearer way

I suspect you haven't found any similar examples because it's an anti-pattern.

If you *do* go for your current approach, you should really try to make it thread-safe, too...

Comment: There is a single instance of `Manager` created at program launch, and it is one of the vital classes of the program. Instances of `Entity` however will probably not be created until some time has passed.

Comment: @Acidic: So it sounds like `Manager` is the dependency to be injected into various other bits of your program. I'll edit my post to reflect that, but it doesn't change the fundamental point: by forcing this initialization to be static, you're making your code harder to test, and the dependencies harder to spot.

Comment: Specifically in this case, `Manager` will never be used on a static scope. I am simply trying to expose it as a protected property for subclasses. There could potentially be tens of thousands of `Entity` subclass instances, and this way I could save the space each of them would take up by having their own references of potential dependencies. It would also un-clutter the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Don't over think it, if that pattern works for you, go with it.  There isn't always a "right" answer, and trying to stick to rigid patterns and practices just for the sake of sticking to them is not a good idea either. IMHO.

Comment: I tend to agree, but I if I can find other examples and learn from that - I would welcome it.

Comment: There are plenty of reasons to stick with good practices in this case, the primary one being testability. It's not "just for the sake of sticking to them".

Comment: @JonSkeet Of course, but I think a lot of people (me included) tend to over think things a little and try to implement the "right" pattern when sometimes something simple, like what he has, will work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for stating the obvious, but you could use the object initializer or the static constructor. Besides that, you can just *not call the method*. Seriously. Why would someone call a method called *initialize* anyway.

What you could do is [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.editorbrowsableattribute.aspx). You can hide the method from IntelliSense and similar with this attribute. Stops it from cluttering up the dropdown too

Comment: Static constructor doesn't help here - there's a parameter.

Comment: Oh, you're right. My mistake. I'll add something *useful* then.

Comment: BTW, somewhat unrelated, but check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228992.aspx) out. Those are amazing.

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation is not thread-safe, but is otherwise reasonable.  If it's intended for use in a multithreaded environment, add locking.

In your sample, the open question is what should happen if multiple callers (possibly from multiple threads) call the initialization method with *different* parameters.  This is what makes your pattern unusual, and prevents you from using the obvious static constructor or object initializer.

Comment: I didn't include a thread safe implementation simply to keep the code short. Anyway, there is only ever a single instance of `Manager` so the only way it could be *ruined* is if `null` is passed, but I consider that a "special case" so I left it out of the example.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use a static constructor?

Of course, you do not have control over when this constructor is called, but don't know if this is a requirement.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Aha indeed. Missed the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a singleton pattern with parameters to only expose certain functionality of the Manager variable.

```
class Entity
{
    private Manager _manager = null;

    public Manager manager
    {
        get
        {
            return _manager;
        }
        set
        {
            if (manager == null)
            {
                _manager = value;
            }
        }
    }
    /* rest of class */
}
```

Now you can use the manager object as any variable, but repeated sets will not modify the value.

```
this.manager = new Manager(0); // sets the manager
this.manager = new Manager(1); // does nothing
```

Now to complete the pattern in your constructor somewhere or at some reset function you might want to do a

```
this._manager = null;
```

Comment: The instance of `Manager` I plan on passing to the `Initialize` method will most likely be created long before the method is actually called. I also don't want the field to be public, simply visible within `Entity` and potentially in inheriting types. I don't think the Singleton pattern fits this case.